# Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; 'FROM portfolio.nashville_housing_data INNER JOIN portfolio.nashville_housing_dat' at line 3

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, sql-update, error-code

Having problem updating my table. Im very new at this so its probably something simple but i cant figure it out.

```
UPDATE a 
SET PropertyAddress = IFNULL(a.PropertyAddress, b.PropertyAddress)
FROM portfolio.nashville_housing_data a
INNER JOIN portfolio.nashville_housing_data b
  on a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID
  and a.UniqueID <> b.UniqueID
WHERE a.PropertyAddress is null
```

MYSQL. Trying to populate values back into PropertyAddress that correspond with ParcelID.

EX.

```
ParcelID  PropertyAddress
11111     1234 St City
11111     NULL
```

Need both values in PropertyAddress to read the same since they have the same ParcelID.

Please help I'm new at this. Thanks.

Comment: There is no `FROM` in an `UPDATE` query. C.f. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

Comment: MySQL differs in its `UPDATE` compared to other RDBMSs like Postgres and SQL Server but does share similar syntax with MS Access. But SQLite, Oracle, and DB2 do not support `FROM` or `JOIN` except in subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

You systax doesn't work in mysql, it must be like below

> ```
> CREATE TABLe nashville_housing_data(ParcelID int,UniqueID int,  PropertyAddress varchar(50))
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE nashville_housing_data a
> INNER JOIN nashville_housing_data b
>   on a.ParcelID = b.ParcelID
>   and a.UniqueID <> b.UniqueID
>
> SET a.PropertyAddress = IFNULL(a.PropertyAddress, b.PropertyAddress)
> WHERE a.PropertyAddress is null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=481ca83619852877cd45088152c3c4a6)*